# take rgb string convert to decimal

Tags: javascript

i have string `'rgb(255,0,0)'` and need to get array of decimals.

The following snippet seems to give me the desired results. Any suggestions, concerns, better ways?

```
var arrRGB = pagedefault.nodelist.style.color.match(/\d+/g); //gives me ["255","0","0"]
arrRGB[0] = Number(arrRGB[0]) / 255;
arrRGB[1] = Number(arrRGB[1]) / 255;
arrRGB[2] = Number(arrRGB[2]) / 255;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would wrap part of the logic in a `for` loop:

```
var arrRGB = pagedefault.nodelist.style.color.match(/\d+/g);
for (var i = 0; i < arrRGB.length; i++) {  
    arrRGB[i] = Number(arrRGB[i]) / 255;
}
```

Otherwise, this looks fine.

Answer (score 3):

```
'rgb(255,0,0)'.match(/\d+/g).map(Number) // ==> [255, 0, 0]
```

works if you have a `map` implemenation.